# web application url routing

Tags: url-routing

I was just wondering if it was common for web applications (like frameworks or cms's) to handle ALL their own url routing/redirections?

Say I had multiple sites and domains all pointing to a single file for processing url requests (WSGI). Urls are stored in a db and then based on the url, fetch the application to be served. Would this be any faster/slower than apache? Other problems? Best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often there is one endpoint for every web application. So there is one page or module which handles all requests for one application.

When using one endpoint for multiple applications, the separate applications become entangled and are not separated anymore. I don't know of any framework that does this.

Which is faster depends on the situation. Using the same application for everything can reduce load and initialization times. With basic URL parsing and dispatching, Apache is probably faster, although this would make very little difference.